# adding remote N number of hosts to AWX

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

Installed Ansible AWX on CentOS 7 without docker. Want to add remote linux hosts(without password) to AWX and run play books and get the results. How to do it? Can any one help. One or two hosts I can add it in web page. How to add 100 remote hosts to AWX. Is there any AWX back end scripting is there to add N number of remote hosts to AWX? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create inventory file in git. Add it to projects in AWX. Create inventory with source as inventory project in AWX. 
Your ssh keys will have to be stored in awx credentials.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create inventory with credentials via web interface.
2. 1. Sign in hosts with AWX via ssh.

      ```bash
      ssh user@hostname
      ```
   2. Sign in container awx_tasks

      ```
      docker exec -it awx_task sh
      ```
3. Create or copy file with hosts ip/hostname

   ```ini
   # cat hosts.ini
   10.0.0.1
   10.0.0.2
   #
   ```
4. Add multiple hosts from file to inventory

   ```bash
   awx-manage inventory_import \
     --inventory-name my-inventory \
     --source hosts.ini
   ```

Worked in my case, AWX 17.0.1